# in-browser real-time audio input options?

Tags: browser, audio

Are there any?  I'm looking for some way to plug in a microphone to a computer and access the stream in real time to do analysis and visualization for display and interaction in-browser (preferably cross-browser).  Any recommendations or pointers toward toolkits or examples would be appreciated--

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to run inside some type of plug-in.  Some options:

- Flash has access to the microphone (see the Actionscript [Microphone](https://web.archive.org/web/20100123173246/http://www.adobe.com:80/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Microphone.html) object).
- Silverlight has microphone access as of [version 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20140511124410/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/innov8showcase/archive/2009/12/14/silverlight-4-accessing-the-web-camera-and-microphone.aspx).
- A signed java applet can also access the microphone.